# existing file gives 404 due to a RewriteCond rule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, http-status-code-404, rewritecond

To redirect a specific domain name to a folder in my public dir, `www/`, I edited `.htaccess` to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ domain.com/$1 [L]
```

Pointing my browser to http://domain.com gives me the following error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /[...]/htdocs/www/domain.com/ was not found on this server.
```

However in my shell I can see this:

```
$ ls -al /[...]/htdocs/www/domain.com/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 user group 3 2012-11-30 12:04 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 8 user group 9 2012-11-30 12:03 ..
-rw-r--r--+ 1 user group 4 2012-11-30 12:04 index.php
```

Editing `.htaccess` to point directly to `index.php` gives the result. An empty `.htaccess` file points correctly to the root directory.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via [this link](http://tips-scripts.com/pointing) I found the proper rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?name\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory/$1 [L]
```

Please see the link itself for a full explanation on proper usage.